# crpe32.dll C# - couldn't add/get parameters to Report

Tags: c#, types, crystal-reports, dllimport

I have problem with printing Crystal Reports using crpe32.dll (we couldn't use ReportDocument clss from CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine for some reasons). When I try to print report without params there aren't any errors. It's enought to use methods from imported dll:

- PEOpenEngine

- PEOpenPrintJob

- PEOutputToPrinter

- PEStartPrintJob

- PEClosePrintJob

- PECloseEngine

But I have problems with methods where I must pass structures, e.g. PEGetNthParameterField or PEAddParameterCurrentValue. I still get "false" as a result and my structures aren't change.

```
private static void PrintTest()
    {
        int o1 = PEOpenEngine();
        if (o1 == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int o2 = PEOpenPrintJob("someReport.rpt");

        short paramCounts = PEGetNParameterFields(o2); // I've got here 4 in one of my real reports

        PEParameterFieldInfo paramInfo = new PEParameterFieldInfo();
        paramInfo.StructSize = 316;
        bool isParamCorrect = PEGetNthParameterField(o2, 0, ref paramInfo); // false :( and unchanged paramInfo

        int o3 = PEOutputToPrinter(o2, 1);
        int o4 = PEStartPrintJob(o2, true);
        int o5 = PEClosePrintJob(o2);

        int oLast = PECloseEngine();
    }

    [DllImport("crpe32.dll")]
    static extern short PEGetNParameterFields(int PrintJob);
    [DllImport("crpe32.dll")]
    static extern bool PEGetNthParameterField(int PrintJob, int parameterN, ref PEParameterFieldInfo parameterInfo);
```

And thing where probably is source of my problem - PEParameterFieldInfo structure

```
    public struct PEParameterFieldInfo
    {
        public int StructSize;
        public int ValueType;
        public int DefaultValueSet;
        public int CurrentValueSet;
        public string Name;
        public string Prompt;
        public string DefaultValue;
        public string CurrentValue;
        public string ReportName;
        public int needsCurrentValue;
        public int isLimited;
        public double MinSize;
        public double MaxSize;
        public string EditMask;
        public int isHidden;
    }
```

Do you have any idea what is here wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of the declaration of the struct that I use, maybe it could be the reason of the error?

```
    private struct PESubreportInfo
    {
        public short StructSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = PE_SUBREPORT_NAME_LEN)]
        public char[] Name;       
    }
```

Comment: How your answer is related to this question? Can you be more specific please?